# Can't get data value on element set by jQuery in Plain JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

The problem is, I am adding a div with some data attributes on ajax call. All content is surrounded in that div. I am using jQuery to set these attributes

```
<div class='x'>Some Content</div>
```

```js
$('.x').data('title', 'some title');
```

When I try to get this via plain/vanilla js it doesn't return anything but with jQuery I get the set data

```
$('.x').data('title') // some title
document.querySelector('.x').getAttribute('data-title') // null
```

Please help in this regard

Comment: jQuery maintains the data ***internally*** instead of reflecting them back in attributes. Only jQuery can read the data set by it.

Comment: Yes, I had that intuition. Any way around? Or should I set it in a Palin JS in the first place

Comment: You can manipulate data attributes. You need to use `.attr` and use `data-foo` instead of `foo`.

Comment: Why would you want a way around? If you have jQuery, use jQuery. If you don't have jQuery, you can't use it to set an element's `.data()` in the first place, you you don't have that issue. (In other words, if you use vanilla JS to set `data-` attributes, you can use vanilla JS to get `data-` attributes.)

Comment: @Tomalak, I wouldn't have any issues as I have jQuery. I am writing something which I want to be independent of jQuery as in progress, I will remove jQuery from codebase

Comment: If you're removing jQuery from your code base, you can't use jQuery's `.data()` and as I said, then there is no problem to solve.

Comment: I think the best way is to set data in Plain JS rather by jQuery as it will be accessible in jQuery as well via `.attr()` if needed